# when i enter a String by input from user and compare it with other string , it always false, explained below ,WHY?

Tags: java

package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = "uni";
    System.out.print("Enter String : ");
    String s2 = sc.next();
    System.out.println(s1+" "+s2 );

    if(s2 == s1){
        System.out.println("Same");
    }else{
        System.out.println("different");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Java string doesn't compare like that . Try Using s2.compare(s1)

Comment: Your formatting needs fixing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use == operators for reference comparison (address comparison) and .equals() method for content comparison. try .equals()

Answer (score 0):

You should compare strings using equals() and not with ==.